# -fno-objc-arc doesn't work at runtime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I downloaded some open source libraries which don't use ARC. I added the `-fno-objc-arc` as suggested on SO which made them compile. However, during runtime I still get errors (that causes crash) like `ARC forbids explicit use of autorelase` . Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: where did you add the flag? Maybe you're missing some files.

Comment: Nope I don't think that's the case

Comment: I was having the same issue with one of the libraries. I solved it by adding `-fno-objc-arc` on each .m file and it works fine. Try it Project -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> Compiler Flags write it there.

Comment: but I don't want to add it to all files though. do think that's a good idea ?

Comment: You should add it to every implementation file of the library. Adding the flag to every file of your project will just cause memory leaks everywhere since you're not managing the memory.

Comment: You can freely mix ARC and non-ARC code. The only important thing is to stick to the naming conventions in the non-ARC code: Methods that have names starting with alloc/init/new/copy return a (+1) retained object, other methods return a autoreleased object. You could run the Xcode static analyzer to find possible problems. - If that doesn't help, you have to provide more information.

Comment: Probably the libraries contains instructions like [myObj retain].

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: @LuaiKalkatawi unfortunately no :/ I do mark the libraries as you suggested but still get runtime errors although it compiles which is strange.. Maybe I should try another another library

Answer (score 0):

Click on the name of the project on the navigation view in the left side, go to
 Targets -> Build Phases and 
add -fno-objc-arc to the "compiler flags" for any relevant files.Simply remove all calls to -release. You're not allowed to call -release under ARC because the compiler will insert all the necessary retain/release calls for you.Please check your file again and clean your project....